# How to position the Placeholder and Search Icon at the center of Search input in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, search, input

In my jQuery mobile app , I need to position the search Icon and Place holder of a search input field at the center , I have tried the folowing code but it didnt work , the placeholder and the icon are still appearing at the left on android devices . Please help me How can I Position the SearchIcon and Placeholder at the center of the Search input field ?

```
<input type="search" id="SearchFilter"  placeholder="Search.." />

 <ul data-role="listview"   data-filter="true"  data-input="#SearchFilter"
    data-split-icon="delete"> 
   // All Elements 
</ul>
```

CSS

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { // its working on jsfiddle but it didnt work on mobile devices

    color: grey; 
    text-align:center;

}
#SearchFilter{

   text-shadow:none; 
   text-align:center;
}


.ui-icon-SearchIcon:after{

   background-image: url(icons/searchIcon.png);
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-position: 0 50%;
   width:32px;
   height:32px;
   text-align:center;
   float:center;    
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting placeholder text in the middle:

Do you want tyled text in the middle too?

If Yes:

```
.ui-input-search input{
    text-align: center;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t9G2h/3/)**

If No:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align:center;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align:center;  
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align:center;  
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align:center; 
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t9G2h/4/)**

You can place the icon in the center if you like, however it does not disappear when you type, so I think it does not make sense.  But if you like:

```
.ui-input-search:after{
   width:18px;
   height:18px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -50px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/t9G2h/5/)**

Comment: @ezankerThanks alot , I have tried  the first demo  the tyled text it works and appears in the center but the place holder still  not appears at the center on android version 4.x !!  How can we fix this  issue

Comment: I visited the fiddle on my nexus android 4.4 and it works fine. Placeholder is in the center.

Comment: @ezankerIts working as webview , but when I use this code in my jQM & Phonegap app for android it works on android version 2.3 but didnt on android v4.x

Comment: @ezankerDo you have any idea about this issue ? Can it be solved?

Comment: It seems a bug in jQM with android version 4 :( , Many Many thanks for your help +1

Comment: i don't know phonegap.

Comment: @ezankerOk,I have  encountered a problem  with JQM   can you help me in solving it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082117/page-background-image-moves-and-stretch-with-collapsible-set-in-jquery-mobile-1 Please ?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [ezanker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22079841/5279911), you can also remove the search icon as there is a class applied once the input gains focus, therefore you could rewrite the css to look like (I also styled the icon position more to my liking):

```
.ui-input-search::after{
   width:18px;
   height:22px;
   left: 50%;
   top: 40%;
   margin-left: -52px;
}
.ui-focus::after{
  left: 10%;
}
.ui-focus ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFffff;
}
.ui-focus :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: white; 
   text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFffff;
}
.ui-focus ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFffff;
}
.ui-focus :-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: white; 
   text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFffff;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cheifly/hega54Lu/1/)