# Page background image moves and stretch with collapsible set in jQuery mobile 1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, background-image, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a Collapsible  set in my jQuery mobile app , the problem is that when I added a background image for the Page as I  expand , close the collapsible the background image is stretch and moves with collapsibles , When i removed these lines from my css :

```
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

this prolem has solved but this has caused another big problem which is that when  I expand a collapsible and then close it the background will shrink " move to up with the collapsibe "and the page part beneath this collapsible becomes without a background "transparent "  this  happens on mobile devices   more than jsFiddle ,this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LvQh/12/)

Please help me how can I solve this Problem  So the collapsibles can be expanded and closed without affecting the page background image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can size your content to the device size using javascript: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3LvQh/13/)**

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function(){
    SizeContent();
});
$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
    SizeContent();
});

function SizeContent(){
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    //if you have a page header
    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    //if you have a page footer
    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();

    /* content div has padding of 1em = 16px (32px top+bottom). This step
   can be skipped by subtracting 32px from content var directly. */
    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;

    $(".ui-content").height(content);   
}
```

Comment: @ezankerThanks alot this solved the problem , but there is a strange  issue occured which is some times not always i need to click the third collapsible "Governorate3" many times to be expanded and if there is a nother collapsible is expanded  this third collapsible  didnt close !

Comment: this occures  just with  collapsible #3 !

Comment: i can't reproduce that behavior... if the op is answered, please accept.

Comment: @ezankerIts occured on the mobile and some times not always , I have reviewed the code but it still occure :( , Sure i will accept and +1

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: mmmStrange, you are welcome this is the minimum thing that can I do :)

Comment: @ezankerI have added a background image  to a page that contains only a list view and as the list element becomes larger as the background also stretch I should do the same thing for this page also  ?

Comment: Probably. Because you have set the image to grow/shrink as the page size changes, setting the size keeps the page the same size and instead adds a scrollbar to the content div.

Comment: @ezankerI have tried the same concept of using SizeContent() in my Page which contains alist view  and this solve the issue the background becomes not stretch  as the list element becomes larger  but this cause a big problem on android version 2.3.6 the content becomes not scrollable at all I cant scroll the list view  and overflow: auto  didnt work on android less than version 4.x  Please  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @ezankerIs size content the only possible solution to prevent the  Page background  from being stretch ? Or Can we solve this Problem in another way ?

Comment: If your background image is a repeating pattern, the best solution is to create a tile and have it repeat on the background instead of stretching it.

Comment: @ezankerNo it didnt a repeating  and i use background-repeat: no-repeat; in my CSS to prevent it from repeating

Comment: @ezankerWhat can we do Now to solve this issue its very important for me to solve it Please I really need your help ..

Comment: as well as overflow: auto, try -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; if that does not work, you should post a new question and see if anyone else has encountered this issue.

Comment: @ezankerI have tried it also and it didnt work on android version lower than 4.x :(

Comment: @ezankerSo the only possible solution to prevent Page background  from stretching is to scroll the content only ??

Comment: @ezankerDid you find any thing new ? I have searched for a soltion with no success  :( I have posted a  question about this issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102458/how-to-prevent-the-page-background-image-from-stretching-in-jquery-mobile-1-4-0  if you can help me

Comment: @ezankerCan you help me in finding an answer for this , since  Iam new in jQuery mobile Is this possible to do with it   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105359/how-to-make-drop-down-panel-in-jquery-mobile-1-4-0

Comment: @ezankerI am very thankful of your help, no one can help me like you Please can you help me more in this question ? Is it possible to make drop down panel in jQM?

Comment: Thanks I will read it , I have thought that we can adjust the Panel using css , I have not thought about using popup