# How to Prevent the page background image from stretching in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, background-image, stretch

In my jQuery mobile 1.4.0 app  I have a Page which contains a list view the Problem is that when I have added a background image for this page as the list elements are becoming  larger as the background stretchs with the content and this apears clearly  on mobile devices more than jsFiddle ,this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9G2h/10/) .

How can I make the background image to be fullscreen and fixed , not stretched with the content? Please help me ..

Here How I add a background image to my Page:

```
#EmPListPage{
   background-image: url('http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/218610/just-ducky-dots-  pinky.gif') !important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }

 #PageContent{

   background: transparent ;    
 }
```

Comment: Add background image to page itself better than content div or any other div.

Comment: @OmarI am already adding the background image to the Page check the jsfiddle ,this  #EmPListPage : is my Page ID

Comment: @OmarDo you have any idea about this issue ? How can I solve it , Please Can you help me?

Comment: Add it `body` and give `.ui-page` a transparent background. http://jsfiddle.net/t9G2h/13/

Comment: @OmarThanks I have tried it like this http://jsfiddle.net/t9G2h/14/   beacuse i have more than on Page  and each page has different BG it worked on the jsfiddle but didnt work for me !  is this beacuse I am using an image from my local directory ? Plaese can you help me more

Comment: I have used an attached image in order to illustrate my problem in the jsfiddle

Comment: @OmarIt still not working in my app Please can you help me more??

Comment: @OmarIts possible to make the background image fixed in order to prevent it from stretching with the content and making the page content scrolls above it in JQM 1.4.0 ? please its really very important to solve this problem and there is no usfull answers on the internet regarding this issue

Comment: @OmarI hope that you can help me In this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106979/custom-arabic-font-is-not-working-on-android-using-jquery-mobile-1-4-0-phonega  , Since you are a palestinian and you know Arabic , and jQuery mobile. I have spent 2 days in searching and trying to solve this problem but with no success :(

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of how screen looks like? Also update your code here? I'll check other question.

Comment: @OmarThe Font is displayed in the default arabic format of the mobile  devices,I have posted a snapshot in the question post

Comment: @OmarI updated the Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106979/custom-arabic-font-is-not-working-on-android-using-jquery-mobile-1-4-0-phonega Your help would be greatlly appreciated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48730/discussion-between-omar-and-user)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to use `contain`, like this:

```
.ui-page {
    background: #000;
    background-image: url("http://bettingmasters.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/19757-football-stadium-1920x1200-sport-wallpaper.jpg");
    background-size: contain;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to attach the background image to the document `body` instead of your container div. Using your CSS in the fiddle:

```
body {
   background-image: url('http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/218610/just-ducky-dots-pinky.gif') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#EmPListPage, #PageContent{    
   background: transparent ;    
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/6zKJg/

Comment: I have tried it but it didnt work at all in jQuery mobile 1.4.0  the background image didnt appear

Comment: @user not sure if you worked it out in the comments on the question, but I added a fiddle (based on your latest version) to demonstrate this answer seems to work in the normal case. Maybe there are unique issues in your actual code, not sure.