# Custom Arabic font is not working on Android using jQuery mobile 1.4.0 & phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, font-face, arabic, custom-font

I have been trying to use custom arabic font file "ttf" in my  jQuery mobile 1.4.0 & Phonegap app for android  but  it didnt work on android version 4.x , the default arabic font displays in the emulator and in the actual device not my custom font .

How can I use custom arabic font in jQuery mobile 1.4.0 and phonegap for android v4.x and makes it work ?

Please help me ..

```
 @font-face{

   font-family:'W3Arabic';
   src: url("Fonts/W3Arabic.ttf"); 
 }

font {
   text-shadow:0 0 0;
   -moz-user-select: none; 
   -webkit-user-select: none; 
   font-family: "W3Arabic" !important;
}
```

The font appears in the default arabic format  of mobile devices as the following image

[image]