# How to make Drop down panel in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel

I have the following Panel in my jQuery mobile app , I want to make it to be drop down  as appears in the following image rather than to be slide from the page edge . Is this can be done in jQuery mobile and  How can i do this  ?

```
<div data-role="page"    id="MainPage"  >

  <div data-role="panel" id="Mainnavpanel" data-theme="b" data-display="overlay" data-      position="right" data-position-fixed="true">

   <ul data-role="listview"><li>
   <a href="#MainPageheader" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn" >Close</a></li>
   <li><a href="Page1.html" class="ui-btn"  data-transition="none">Page1</a></li>
  <li><a href="Page2.html" class="ui-btn"  data-transition="none">Page2</a></li>
  <li><a href="Page3.html" class="ui-btn"  data-transition="none">Page3</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

   <div  data-role="header"   id="MainPageheader"  data-position="fixed"  data-tap-     toggle="false" data-fullscreen="false">

    <a href="#Mainnavpanel" data-role="button"  class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn- icon-notext ui-nodisc-icon ui-icon-bars"></a>
    <div> <font size="6px"> Main Page </font></div>

    </div> 
    <div data-role="content" >

    //content
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use *popup* widget to simulate dropdown menu.

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, a new attribute `data-arrow` is added to *popup* widget. This creates an *arrow* which can be positioned anywhere in popup.

> ### [Arrow:](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/)
>
> The popup can display an arrow along one of its edges when it opens if the `data-arrow` attribute is set. The attribute can take a value of `true`, `false`, or a string containing a comma-separated list of edge abbreviations ("l" for left, "t" for top, "r" for right, and "b" for bottom). For example, if you set `data-arrow="r,b"` then the arrow will only ever appear along the bottom or right edge of the popup. true is the same as "l,t,r,b" and `false` or `""` indicates that the popup should be displayed without an arrow.

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupID" data-arrow="t">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Add `data-rel="popup"` to button to call popup.

```
<a href="#popupID" data-rel="popup">Menu</a>
```

To modify arrow's size, check this [link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup-arrow-size/).

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TFX6p/)**