# jQuery Mobile Menu Header Button Collapsible

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile - i have 2 buttons in  my header.

[image]

The one on the right (menu) i would like to be a list that collapses down. I've been looking around for the last hour and cannot find a straight forward example that shows how to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can you use a popup widget (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/) placed below the button?

Comment: as @ezanker said, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22147795/1771795