# how to make pop screen as shown in images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

[image]

I am making a demo of pop up screen as show in image. I have some issue my triangle is look "v"..how to come pop up above the option button? can we make same as in show in above. My pop up come below the button. it should come above the button ?

```
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #002952;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}
.menu{
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jHjDL/1/

Comment: use popover of bootstrap. That will be the simplest.

Comment: actually i am using jqm .so it css conflict the bootstrap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22147795/1771795 for JQM 1.4

Comment: You can at least check it's CSS and copy paste that :D

Answer (score 0):

So I looked at your fiddle and [this is the best edit I can come up with](http://jsfiddle.net/jHjDL/3/):

```
<div style='position:relative;'>
    <div style='position:fixed; bottom:0px;'> <a href="#menuPopUp" data-rel="popup" id="btn1" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" data-mini="true">Options</a>

        <div data-role="popup" id="menuPopUp">
            <ul data-role="listview" class="menu">
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Edit</a>
                </li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Call</a>
                </li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">SMS</a>
                </li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Edit</a>
                </li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">Call</a>
                </li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">SMS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I took the liberty of adding some wrappers and pushing the options link to the bottom of the page so that the menu can pop overtop of  it. JQuery UI handles this by itself, nothing special needs to be done to make it show up above the link, the link just has to be in the page somewhere that the menu can pop over.

After that I made a small change to the css to invert the arrow:

```
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-top: 15px solid #002952; /*<-- make it border top to make a down arrow */
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

Now it seems to do what you want it to do. One thing I have noticed is that when you re-size the window the position of the menu gets all funny.  I think this is a quirk of the UI popup and can only be fixed if you use custom CSS to display it.