# Basic Header with jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have been looking to develop a mobile-device website. I've been looking at the available mobile layout frameworks and am currently looking at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Since there's no room to display the menu all the time, I was thinking I want a button on the left side of the title bar that opens a drop-down menu. Similar to the drop-down menu on the left of the Facebook header.

[image: Facebook Mobile Layout]

I was surprised to find no examples of a menu like this. Can anyone point me to some examples of this, or perhaps offer some tips?

Comment: You can find it here http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/side%20menu/

Comment: Thanks, but are these separate plug ins needed to do this?

Comment: Yes those are plugins... And should work nicely. And there are many of those available for free :)

Comment: Have you tried JQM panels? Or are you looking for a drop down menu like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105359/how-to-make-drop-down-panel-in-jquery-mobile-1-4-0/22147795#22147795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That element is commonly called a Side Menu, and there are ample resources online for it

quick google search gave me these results, but there are plenty more, good luck.

http://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still struggling with the face that jQuery Mobile doesn't support this basic type of layout. Perhaps it's not the right framework for me.

Comment: @JonathanWood ive recently been playing around with ionic, give that a look!

Comment: Thanks, but Ionic seems married to Angular JS. I don't want to have to learn anything like that right now.